# Is it possible to Copy images from web to your Hard Drive?

Tags: php, curl, download, file-management

I am trying to create a page for just personal use. What I want to do is, create a system through which I can download images to my local hard disk, directly by providing the link through a **localhost** like WAMP. The reason I am trying to do is, I want the images to be automatically sorted onto my hard disk. My form field will be something like this

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
   <input type="text" name="URL" id="URL" />
   <input type="text" name="category" id="category" />
   <input type="text" name="subcategory" id="category" />
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now, in the `process.php`

```
//This is just a sample... So please ignore the roughness of the coding

copy($_POST['url'],$_POST['category']."/".$_POST['subcategory']."/somename.jpg");

// If you noticed, the categories and subcategories are actually the name of directory, where I want the picture to go be saved....
```

I am thinking my approach is wrong. How can I achieve something like this?

### Error

```
Warning: copy(images/image.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

Comment: `copy(source, destination)`, where is your destination?

Comment: @ajreal, please read the question nicely, I am sure you will the find the destination mentioned as `$_POST['category']."/".$_POST['subcategory']."/somename.jpg"` above..

Comment: **NO**, your code is using relative path

Comment: @ajreal, What are you suggesting, Shall I use `http://localhost/myimages/images/somename.jpg` as my destination

Comment: **NO**, you should use absolute path, and make sure the directory is created and your server has enough permission to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I used curl instead to achieve what i am expecting. Here is the piece of code

```
$img = $_POST['url'];
$fullpath = $_POST['category']."/".$_POST['subcategory']."/".basename($img);
$ch = curl_init ($img);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
$rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);                   
$fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `allow_url_fopen` is true in the php.ini and your `PHPVERSION` is >= 4.3.0 your code should work.

Comment: The only problem seems to be your path. In the dir where your download.php script is, have to be the directories you are able to set via form...

Comment: i think copy function can copy file from host server only. am i right on this?

Comment: @Simer: it is possible to copy a file from a remote host with `copy()` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can first download from php script document from specified url, then give http-client link to download locally stored file. or put document content to output stream:

```
 $cont = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=' . $new_file_name));
  echo($cont);
```

Comment: Doesn't this code give a donwload option instead of saving the file. I want the files to automatically saved on to a specified directory.

Comment: no, direct saving is not possible my means of server php-script. it's not safe from the system security point of view. only via download. or using php script locally. running from cmd-like like php.exe download_img.php